# Exception not caught in map when using a placeholder

Tags: scala

I have just come across a quite baffling anomaly in scala. Say I define the following three lines of code:

```
def f(d: Int): String = throw new RuntimeException("Catch this")
Some(0).map { x => try { f(x) } catch { case ex: Exception => println("Caught first"); "" } }
Some(0).map { try { f(_) } catch { case ex: Exception => println("Caught second"); "" } }
```

When I run this only "Caught first" gets printed out. It seems that when I use a placeholder in my map function the catch body is never invoked.

Can someone say why this would it be? Could it be a compiler bug? I have tested it with scala 2.11.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version expands to:

```
Some(0).map { try { x => f(x) } catch { case ex: Exception => println("Caught second"); "" } }
```

That is, `f(_)` expands to `x => f(x)` *within* the `try` block, so it remains an unapplied function. The unapplied function will not throw an exception, so the `try/catch` block returns it and it is used by `Option#map` where it throws the exception.